# Exponential function in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

Can I convert this exponential function in QGIS with Raster Calculator ?

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can.

Assuming alpha = 0.5, beta = 3.2 and 2.71828 for Euler's number, the formula in raster calculator of QGIS would be:

```
2.71828 ^ (-0.5*"NDVI@"/(3.2 - "NDVI@"))
```

Testing it with next NDVI raster:

[image]

formula in raster calculator looks like:

[image]

After click in OK, I got:

[image]

Raster values were also calculated with the help of a manual calculator and they match the formula (visualized with Value Tool plugin of QGIS). It works!